# Zend framework passing data from plugin to the controller

Tags: php, zend-framework

From one of my controller plugin, I want to pass a value to the controller. I have tried it using the Zend_Registry functionality. But it is not working.

In my plugin, I have tried setting registry key as follows.

```
Zend_Registry::set('msg','hello world!');
echo Zend_Registry::get('msg');
```

In my controller's action method, I tried to access it as follows

```
Zend_Registry::get('msg');
```

but nothing returns. In plugin it sets the value and outputting it. Am i missing anything? Or is this not a right way to do this? If so can someone help me?

plugin below

```
    class COM_Application_Controller_Plugin_TestPlugin extends Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract 
{ 
    public function preDispatch(Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request) 
    { 
        $currentController = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()
             ->getRequest()
             ->getControllerName(); 
         $moduleName = $request->getModuleName(); 
         Zend_Registry::set('msg','Hello Word!'); 
     } 
}
```

Comment: make sure your plugin is registered

Comment: the plug in is registered and rest of the plugin functionality working fine

Comment: when you are setting Registry value ? in what method ? post the plugin as well

Comment: the registry value is set in the plugin predispatch metod.

Comment: please post the plugin source code

Comment: ok.. i am unable to edit my question. so i am pasting the plugin below

class COM_Application_Controller_Plugin_TestPlugin extends Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract
{
 public function preDispatch(Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request)
 {
  $currentController = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRequest()->getControllerName();
  $moduleName        = $request->getModuleName();
  
  Zend_Registry::set('msg','Hello Word!');
  
 }
 
}

sorry, it removes all line breaks when i save

Comment: your code looks fine to me, probably problem is somewhere else...